# VBS Questions from a Noob

Tags: search, vbscript, criteria

I am new to vbs and need to know how to search a column for certain criteria then copy any rows matching that criteria to a new spreadsheet.  I have several categories of data that I pull all from a single spreadsheet but it requires a lot of 'filter on this column, filter on this column, eyeball for this criteria in another column, if it matches then copy and paste the row to the proper category'.  I basically want to take all of this manual effort and automate it.

My second question is when searching in certain columns I have dates in I need to find rows that fit the criteria of '21 days or closer to the current date'.  How can I specify the script to look at the dates and copy and paste all rows that are no further out than 21 days from the current date?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us your VBS code that you've tried and does not work?

Comment: @istepaniuk - nudging a student who needs a plan/concept to produce code is futile and nasty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you interested in creating a custom macro using VBS?  Adding VB file under Development/Visual Basic, You can process rows and columns.

```
Sub CountX(pRowStart As Integer, pRowStop As Integer, pColStart As Integer, pColStop As Integer, pObjGrp As String)
            Dim x As Integer
            Dim xRow As Integer
            Dim xCol As Integer
            Dim wSht As Worksheet

            x = 0
            '**** create object reference to worksheet object.
            Set wSht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

            '**** set cell control values
            xRow = 1
            xCol = 3        
            Do While xRow < pRowStop + 1
                Do While xCol < pColStop + 1
                    If UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(xRow, xCol)) = "X" Then
                        x = x + 1
                    End If
                    xCol = xCol + 1
                Loop
                xCol = pColStart
                xRow = xRow + 1
            Loop
    End Sub
```

You can also add this to your code to activate another sheet and set the value to row 1 column 3

```
Sheets(psSheetName).Activate 
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "value"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Greg. Sorry took so long to get back on this in response to everyone's responses.  This helped tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to automate the manipulation of spreadsheet (Excel?) data: Both start with specifying your tasks in plain/natural language (e.g. 'copy all rows with ??-date 21 days greater/greater equal/smaller/smaller equal than the current date from sheet ?? (row/col?) to sheet ?? (row/col?)' and then

1. use the macro recorder to get the VBA code to solve the task and 'port' it to VBScript
2. translate the task decriptions to SQL statements and execute them on an ADO connection to the spreadsheet

Whether the first or the second way is better for you depends on your knowledge and skills.